# Swift macOS - -[_SwiftValue objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, unrecognized-selector, presentation-layer

Here is a truncated version of the error:

```
2018-09-30 16:11:12.786201-0700 MacPlayground[57283:3255328] -[_SwiftValue objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040004464e0
2018-09-30 16:11:12.786610-0700 MacPlayground[57283:3255328] [General] -[_SwiftValue objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040004464e0
2018-09-30 16:11:12.793434-0700 MacPlayground[57283:3255328] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f6a12db __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff66856c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f739db4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f617820 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f6171e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff4aa0cf8c _ZL9getValuesP7NSValuePdRm + 51
    6   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff4aa0cbba -[NSValue(CAAnimatableValue) CA_interpolateValue:byFraction:] + 159
    7   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff4a996855 -[CABasicAnimation applyForTime:presentationObject:modelObject:] + 532
    8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff4a9a6df1 _ZN2CA5Layer18presentation_layerEPNS_11TransactionE + 683
    9   UICore                              0x000000010035d5a0 $SSo6NSViewC6UICoreE23currentlyPresentedValue33_87359CB0FAD3031CD028C558F7C6F5D1LL6forKeyypSgSS_tF + 1248)
```

This occurs (under certain unknown conditions) when I call `layer.presentation()` on the backing layer of an NSView. Does anyone know why getting the presentation layer could result in the unrecognized selector error?

Comment: That may happen in various cases when you have setup the `NSView` (or something containing the `NSView`) wrongly. Please try to show all relevant codes, very likely animation settings, but can be something other.